# Trying to figure out Gmail login in Wireshark

Tags: authentication, penetration-test, sniffer

In my pentesting lab I'm using ettercap for do a mitm to a XP VM.

I go to gmail, accepting the false certification, and here I start to sniff with wireshark. I put some false account like pentest/pentestpasswd try to login and stop the sniffer.

In this moment, ettercap shows that user/password stolen. I'm trying to find that info in Wireshark too, but I can't. Even following the TCP stream, I can't.

Some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you wont be able to see it plain text in wireshark. the packets are encrypted ettercap is acting as a relay, your pc connects to ettercap which decrypts the login info then encrypts it again to send it to the real gmail server

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking that ettercap sent them decrypted.

Comment: If im not mistaken Max you are referring to the need to do a SSL strip.